# CS0103: The name 'test' doesn't exist in the actual context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cordova, azure

I'm coding a mobile app who should save some infos in a private remote database.
Of course, I can't access public websites of my enterprise to implement a webservice. On the other hand, we have a mailbox with a permanently activated macro who is able to activate another macro when it receives an email with a predefined subject. So, potentially, that 'robot' can save infos I want it to save.

I had to think at different solutions, I choosed one, but I am less and less sure of my choice.

Anyway, my mobile app is developed with Cordova and Ionic Framework. I didn't want to implement a plugin to open my user's mail client, I wanted my mail to be sent automatically.

Finally, I found SendGrid, I thought I could implement it directly in my mobile app, but I didn't make it (If somebody dit it, could you tell me so ? It could delete some steps in my app)

So I reflected about put a third actor in my process. PHP appeared as the best : I'm used to it, and I know we can easily send an email while the SMTP is defined ... It's too bad I can't implement webservices in public websites of my enterprise  ^^

Another solution appeared to me : to use Microsoft's Azure service. So i created an ASP.net app of which here is the only sample of code. That method sends correctly my email (the first thing I wanted to verify), but it's unable to recover my form's data.

I wanted to use `Request.Form.Keys` to see what does it recover before I treat my data, and it didn't recover anything so I didn't understand.
I finally created that test String to delete a doubt who was growing. I put a breakpoint on the next line, where my Datetime is instantiate, to see what was in my test ... and it doesn't exist.

Here is the error I can see with my breakpoint :
`AzureSendgrid.Controllers.HomeController.SendMail() : test value is error CS0103: The name 'test' doesn't exist in the actual context`

```
public void SendMail()
{
    //System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection test = Request.Form.Keys;
    String test = "test";
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(test);


    DateTime now = DateTime.Now; // Here is a breakpoint

    // Create the email object first, then add the properties.
    SendGridMessage myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
    myMessage.AddTo(emailTo);
    myMessage.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom, "Appli Mobile");
    myMessage.Subject = "Appli Mobile Testing SendGrid";
    myMessage.Text = "Date-Heure d'envoi : " + now.Day + "/" + 
                        now.Month + " " + now.Hour + ":" + now.Minute + ":" + now.Second;
    //myMessage.AddAttachment 

    // Create a Web transport, using API Key
    var transportWeb = new Web(api_key)

    // Send the email.
    //var t = transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
}
```

That error is pretty clear, and I could have understand it if there was not juste one line between the initialization and use of my test variable.
If anyone can see anything to help me, it would be nice !

Sorry for potential errors in this message, I'm French.

Comment: this is English community

Comment: Sorry! I edit in a few minutes